# angular cli disableHostCheck true is not working

Tags: angular-cli

Am using Angular CLI: 6.2.2 , Node: 8.11.1 and OS: darwin x64
This is my etc hosts
127.0.0.1       dinesh.mysocialapi.com

This is my comment 
node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host  0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true

am getting this error how to fix ?
Loading failed for the  with source “http://dinesh.mysocialapi.com/vendor.js”. dinesh.mysocialapi.com:34

Answer (score 1):

The actual flag to disable host check is `--disable-host-check`

just add `--disable-host-check` to your command like `ng serve --disable-host-check`